# Salesforce Survey Validation formulas

Tags: validation-rule, survey

Does anybody have any experience with Salesforce custom validations in Surveys? I am trying to get a validation to work for a short text question that will accept either a whole number or a 2 digit decimal number. I can get it to accept 2 digit decimal with this: `[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]`

But that will not allow it to accept a number without a decimal point. Every other formula I have tried always gives an error. I have noticed that the different REGEX examples in Saleforce's survey documentation don't work as shown. For example, their example of an email validation:

```
REGEX({!Email_Address},“[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}“)
```

gives an error, although I was able to figure that one out. But I can't get it to accept a formula to validate a whole number or a number with 2 decimal spots.

Comment: these regex questions can also be addressed on stackoverflow

Comment: Please note that this question is not specifically about regex. It is a question about regex formulas not working with Salesforce surveys. Validations that would normally work for normal fields will not work for me in the surveys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` for OR so for your example: `[0-9]|[0-9]+[.][0-9][0-9]`

There are enhancements you could make, for instance: `[0-9]*|[0-9]*.[0-9]{1,2}`. This would allow a postive integer or a positive decimal up to 2 decimal places.